# Migrate profiles from x86 to x64 Vista?

Tags: migration, windows-vista, 64-bit, user-profile, sid

I want to move my Vista install from x86 to x64, but retain the user profiles with all the files and so. Microsoft does not seem to provide an upgrade option

In the XP days, recreate the user accounts and xcopy the profiles after logon/logoff*. Is there another other way; officially supported?

<sup>*Necessary to create and register the profile directories</sup>

Answer (score 9):

So the real question here is that you want to move a profile from one OS install to another, retaining appropriate permissions on the user profile. While registry hacks may work, there's a better way.

In the [Windows AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753), there's a tool called "User State Migration Tool". Its explicit purpose is moving profiles from one OS to another (upgrading them as necessary as well), and [is well documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560801%28WS.10%29.aspx).